# Magento2: how to add extra 2% amount on grand total and how to display final value after grand total?

Tags: magento2, checkout, grand-total

In magento 2 how to add **extra 2% ammount** on **grand total**.

Comment: You can check with : magento2 extra fee/charge module.

Comment: Thanks for comment if you use extra fee module its taking for subtotal but i need for grand total,,, on grand total i need to add 2% extra ammount that to based on payment